# Use of Modal Verbs 'Must' and 'Will' to Express Certainty

Tags: modal-verbs

When I see examples of 'must' or 'will' showing certainty, I find that the main verb is either a stative verb or a present participle preceded by 'be'. How different are the two sentences in the following pairs:

```
He will be coming. VS He will come.
He must be working. VS He must work.
```

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has reasonably good coverage of [modal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb#Modal_verbs_in_Germanic_languages).

*Must* is stronger than *will*: *must* indicates a requirement, whereas *will* indicates a prediction of future action without regard to its cause. If someone will do something, we don't know whether it's because they have to, or they want to, or it's just a matter of circumstance.

See also [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) which outlines the specific meanings of the modal verbs MUST, MAY, SHOULD, and SHALL in requirements documents that cite RFC 2119.

Answer (score 1):

The two phrases with *must* are actually quite different.

*He must be working*:

I am expressing certainty that he is currently working.

*He must work*:

In general, work is something he has to do.

---

The two phrases with *will* are similar, with only a subtle difference.

*He will be coming*:

I am expressing certainty that he will come, and am considering that action (of him coming) as continuous; that is, I am thinking of it happening over some time period.

This suggests certainty that his transit will occur.

*He will come*:

I am expressing certainty that he will come, and am considering that action (of him coming) as discrete; that is, it is one complete action in my mind.

This suggests certainty that his arrival will occur.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'must' in many cases seems to me as lacking of a choice in the matter, like 'have to'. My more used word 'will' allow freedom of choice.