# Use of "Must' and 'Should' for Future Certainty

Tags: modal-verbs

Is it possible to use 'must' or 'should' to express certainty in the future? Is the sentence 'He must/should be coming tomorrow.' correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of Modal Verbs 'Must' and 'Will' to Express Certainty](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38965/use-of-modal-verbs-must-and-will-to-express-certainty)

Comment: hmm, I take that back; it's the same general subject but this question is different.

Answer (score 2):

*Should* is never certain; it indicates a correct or expected action to be taken.

*Must* indicates a requirement.

The only problem with your sentence is that by adding *be* to the modal verb, *must be* and *should be* weaken the certainty, and indicate that the speaker is guessing or making a deduction. I'm not sure when this connotation came into being; the literal meaning of *must be* and *should be* is strong, but sometime  we started to use *must be* and *should be* as a weaker expression of certainty.

(This is covered in the Wikipedia article on [modal verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_verb); [epistemic modality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) indicates a degree of belief, whereas [deontic modality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality) indicates a degree of requirement.)

The strongest modal verb in English is *shall*; it's rather formal though.

If you just want to express certainty but not cause, it's fine to say *He will be coming tomorrow.*

Comment: Epistemic *should'* can express a **degree** of certainty. The certainty is, for example, greater than that expressed by *may/might* and not as great as that expressed by *will*.   I don't know what you men by 'The strongest modal verb in English is *shall*'. Strongest in what way?

Comment: The "requirement" aspect of *must* is expressed by *"He **must come** tomorrow"*. There seems to be little or no difference in meaning between ***will come*** and ***will be coming*** as replacements there. But as you say - if we switch to ***must be coming*** it suddenly becomes a lot less of a certainty/requirement. It's just a slightly stronger way of saying *"[Given what I now know,] **The only outcome/explanation I can think of** is that he will come tomorrow"*.